# Alternatives to recordmydesktop?

Tags: video-recording, video-capture

I am using Recordmydesktop to record skype conversations. After an important recording, I went to the linux terminal where the recording was supposed to be taking place and all I could see was:

*Segmentation fault (core dumped)*

Recordmydesktop does to me this kind of thing sometimes, usually it happens with the most important recordings. Please provide a working alternative desktop recording software for linux.

Comment: RecordMyDesktop has been running good on my 14.04 xubuntu laptop. I had problems with Istanbul

Comment: I have 14.04 too.

Comment: You did file a bug report, right?

Comment: Not yet. If you give me a link to the relevant information, I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used both Simple Screen Recorder and Open Broadcaster Software. SSP is really simple and easy to use, and I believe it's in the Ubuntu app store. OBS requires a command line installation and the installation of ffmpeg as well, which often has to be compiled. OBS is a little more complex to use and might be overkill for your needs, but it is very powerful.

Comment: Thanks. SSP seems OK. I have not yet tested it in long recordings though.